# Text boxes inside Jquery tabs

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

Can text boxes can be added inside the jquery tabs???
Can I have a different theme for the tab and a different theme for the text boxes inside??

Am a begineer to jquery and it would be useful if I can get tutorials..

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. As for the themes, you can preview default themes here: [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

**Edit:**

I think the ['getting started' guide](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started) is pretty good!
When you [build your custom download](http://jqueryui.com/download), you can select the theme you want in the selectbox at the top right!

Good luck

Comment: @Bart-Do you know any tutorial to the same??

Comment: I updated my answer with some more information. I hope it helps

Comment: If it's worth sharing, please add it to your comment! I'm curious now :)